# ondragenter alert the container's .id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I've an img that I just wanna drop in the div called `#div1`. When I drag over the div I would like to get the container's id, but this is making lots of alerts, no just one....

```
 <img id="drag1" 
      src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif" 
      draggable="true" 
      ondragstart="drag(event, this)" 
      width="336" 
      height="69"/>

  <div id="div1"
       ondrop="drop(event)"  
       ondragenter="allowDrop(event, this)">
  </div>
```

JS :

```
function allowDrop(ev, obj)
{
    alert(obj.id);
}
```

So Why I'm recibing lots of Alerts???

See the Demo there :  http://jsfiddle.net/PbjJv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

The `ondragover` event is **fired every pixel** your cursor moved on the `div`.
Try to use `ondragleave` event which is fired when you **release** the mouse button.

---

### Solution

Use the `ondragleave` event on your div :

### HTML

```
 <div id="div1"  ondragleave="allowDrop(event, this)"></div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PbjJv/1/)

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same ?? It crashes with my script ... :'(

Comment: I can't see anything there 'cause Chrome crashes and it gets  closed   lol

Comment: Send a report to Google and try updating your browser. This code works fine here. If the JSFiddle works for you, then this code isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This accepted answer is incorrect.

From the MDN:

> The drop event is fired when an element or text selection is dropped on a valid drop target.

And:

> The dragleave event is fired when a dragged element or text selection leaves a valid drop target.

Calling allowDrop() when the `ondragleave` event fires would allow dropping to the DIV after the drag has left that element. The element in question would not receive the final `ondrop` event when the user relase the mouse button.

The question seem to have been edited, it seems fine to me at this point. The jsfiddle referenced in the OPs question suggests this as it use `ondragover` instead of `ondragenter` on **div1**.